# Looking for Century Model 6210 Portable Toilet Waste Tank Drain Thread Size

Tags: diy, human-waste, rv

What is the thread size on the waste tank drain? I can’t find a female connector to dump at a RV dump (step on 3” cap). Looking to build my own. The research I have done indicates a Buttress thread but not sure on size.

Comment: Have you tried asking at the company itself or some other supplier?